# PL/SQL Insert ignore everything

Tags: plsql, compiler-errors

I have such a problem that I wrote a code that first uses a select to check whether the table exists, if it exists, it writes to dbms that 'it exists' and continues, if it doesn't exist, it creates it with an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE part.
After that, there are 2 inserts that should be inserted into the table to load data.
However, if the table does not exist, the code ignores everything and immediately prints an error stating that the table does not exist.

```
DECLARE
  table_count NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO table_count
  FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name = 'test_table';

  IF table_count > 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Table is exist');
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE test_table (column1 NUMBER, column2 VARCHAR2(50))';
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO test_table (column1, column2) VALUES (1, 'Value1');
  INSERT INTO test_table (column1, column2) VALUES (2, 'Value2');

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Any idea why this happen ? Thanks for the help. :)

i Try to refactor the code. Put the insert into another if else state; But the code ignore everything if the table not exist. . .

Comment: If a table doesn't exist an INSERT INTO statement (any statement referencing it) can't be parsed, you must do everything with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Thanks man... That what the solution. <3

Answer (score 0):

Everything statically referenced in a PL/SQL block must exist before the code can compile. As p3Consulting suggested, you must change *all* references to TEST_TABLE to be dynamic. For example, the below code also makes the INSERTs dynamic:

```
DECLARE
  table_count NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO table_count
  FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name = 'test_table';

  IF table_count > 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Table is exist');
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE test_table (column1 NUMBER, column2 VARCHAR2(50))';
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[INSERT INTO test_table (column1, column2) VALUES (1, 'Value1')]';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[INSERT INTO test_table (column1, column2) VALUES (2, 'Value2')]';

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

---

In addition, you might want to check how you are getting your errors. The entire error stack contains helpful error messages and also points out the exact lines and columns of the errors. That should be enough information to realize that the INSERT statement was the issue. It is unfortunately common for many error handlers to cutoff most of the error stack. Make sure whatever program you are using to run SQL is displaying the *entire* error stack, which would look something like this:

```
ORA-06550: line 15, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 15, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 16, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 16, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```